# Applying a DirectX shader to a rotated texture in XNA

Tags: xna, rotation, directx, shader

I had a dynamic light shader for which the shaded sprite was fine in my own test program, but started resembling an eclipse once I imported it into my friend's physics based game.  I narrowed it down by simplifying the gradient to be purely based on the X value within the shape, and making the outside of the circle in the sprite red, but as you can see, the rotation continues to cause problems (can't post images, so here's links to the album).

Circle at different rotations(not in order, but labelled by radian values): https://i.stack.imgur.com/yP05B.jpg

Everything I researched about matrix math says I am using the correct formula for rotation, but I figure maybe I'm doing something wrong.  Here is my .fx shader code:

```
float rotationrads; /*assumed rotation is in radians*/
sampler TextureSampler: register(s0);

float4 staticlight(float2 Tex: TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{
float4 Color = tex2D(TextureSampler, Tex);





    float2 NewTex;

    /*Get the new X and Y values by applying the UV formula with the rotation*/
    NewTex.x = (Tex.x * cos(rotationrads)) - (Tex.y * sin(rotationrads));
    NewTex.y = (Tex.y * sin(rotationrads)) + (Tex.y * cos(rotationrads));

if(Color.a > 0.0)
{
    Color.r = (Color.r * NewTex.x);
    Color.g = (Color.g * NewTex.x);
    Color.b = (Color.b * NewTex.x);
}
else
{
    Color.r = 100;
    Color.g = 0;
    Color.b = 0;
    Color.a = 100;
}


return Color;  
}

technique StaticLightOnly
{
pass Pass1
{
    PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 staticlight();
}
}
```

If anyone has experience with sprite-based rotation in 2d shaders, I'd appreciate any help with this!  Thanks in advanced!

Comment: What exactly are you trying? Why do use use the rotated texture coordinates to alter the color? Don't you want to sample the texture at the new position?

Comment: Yeah, essentially, the circle is a body part within the Farseer physics engine, and due to motion and being knocked over, the shading has to account for the parts rotating.  As you can see, when the circle is in starting position, the shading works, and is darker on the left.  This also works when i add a dynamic light source.  If I don't account for rotation, the darkness rotates with the circle, which won't work for the external light source.

Comment: Sorry, I ran out of edit time.  The circle is spinning in XNA/Farseer.  The shader has to keep the shadow on the left.  Not accounting for rotation seems to make the shadow rotate with the circle, so I need to account for the rotation being passed into the shader to keep the shadow on the left.  I get the feeling my rotation algorithm is at fault, since I stripped out literally every other calculation I made for dynamic lighting.

Comment: Ah, I understand. The rotation is performed about the origin. Therefore, you should move the tex coords by `(-0.5, -0.5)`, perform the rotation and move by `(0.5, 0.5)`.

Comment: That worked!  I can't mark your comment as an answer, but if you repost it to the answer link I can check it off so you get credit!

I changed the code to:

  NewTex.x = ((Tex.x - 0.5) * cos(rotationrads)) - ((Tex.y - 0.5) * sin(rotationrads)) + 0.5;
  NewTex.y = ((Tex.y - 0.5) * sin(rotationrads)) + ((Tex.y -0.5) * cos(rotationrads)) + 0.5;

Answer (score 1):

Because rotations are performed about the origin, you have to move the rotation center (0.5, 0.5) to the origin, execute the rotation and then undo the translation.